# How do I complete a Cargo Link quest?

Tags: starfield

One of my quests is to establish a Cargo Link for Uranium at Akila.
*(I can't find any further information in my mission logfile how to do that.)*

I have found the console near the landing zone in Akila. The middle one (of 3) has a blue icon. If I press `E` (PC) on this console I get a screen with many sections and orange borders. One entry indicates **Uranium** but there is no obvious way to click on anything on this screen.

[image]

How do I activate or establish this Cargo Link?

Do I have to bring some Uranium to this Link and "sell" or "transmit" it from my inventory to the console?

Do I have to create an outpost first over a Uranium field and mine it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an outpost, and build an **Cargo Link Inter-System**. (Alternatively, the cheaper, regular **Cargo Link** if your uranium outpost is in the same system.)

Fill the **Outgoing** storage with **Uranium** (by hand, or preferably by mining at the outpost— you built it on a planet and near a uranium node, right?) *and* (if using the Inter-System link) fill the gas storage with **He-3** (helium gas) to power it.

Once the uranium is in the Outgoing storage, it will show up in these trade consoles. (You can also use the console on the link you just built.)

(There are some other details like connecting up all the containers, powering it all, etc.— general Outpost building stuff. I won't describe every step of outpost building here in detail.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Mufasa wasn't correct, **TLDR; you don't power the Inter-System Cargo Link.**

**Create your Uranium outpost**

1. Find a planet with Uranium
2. Find a Uranium node on the planet (away from generated buildings)
3. Plop an outpost down near it
4. Place an 'Extractor - Uranium' on the node
5. Power the extractor with solar/wind/etc
6. Hook outgoing link from extractor to a solids container
7. Create either:

   - a Cargo-Link if you are within the same solar system
   - an Inter-System Cargo Link **WITHOUT** power (He-3) if you are in another system
8. Create an outgoing link from your solids container (or a fabricator in some cases) to the Outgoing box on the Cargo Link

**Hook up to Akila**

1. Go to Akila
2. As described in the question, not far from where your ship lands, there will be a few terminals
3. You will see your Uranium outpost to link now